# Android calendar warning of API level

Tags: android, calendar, warnings, android-calendar

I am developing an application in which i am **setting reminder** using following code :

```
// Creation of Event.
ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
// Set calendar as 1 for default calendar.
eventValues.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
// Set title as user define.
eventValues.put(Events.TITLE, "Reminder");
// Set description as user define.
eventValues.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "You set the reminder.");
// Set location as user define.
eventValues.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "India");
// Set start time as system time or time converted in milliseconds.
eventValues.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
// Set status of event as 1.
eventValues.put("eventStatus", 1);
// Set visibility of event as 3 (public).
eventValues.put("visibility", 3);
// Set transparency as 0. No other app seen through reminder.
eventValues.put("transparency", 0);
// Set alarm as 1. Ringing.
eventValues.put(Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);

// Set Event in calendar.
Uri eventUri = getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), eventValues);
// Getting ID of event in Long.
long eventID = Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());

/***************** Event: Reminder(with alert) Adding reminder to event *******************/
// String to access default google calendar of device for reminder setting.
String reminderUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders";      
ContentValues reminderValues = new ContentValues();

// Set reminder on Event ID.
reminderValues.put("event_id", eventID);
// Set reminder minute before.
reminderValues.put("minutes", 10);
// Set method of reminder
reminderValues.put("method", 1);        

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
//Setting reminder in calendar on Event.
Uri reminderUri = getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(reminderUriString), reminderValues);
```

But the issue is that i am getting **warning** as:

```
Field requires API level 14 (current min is 8): android.provider.CalendarContract.Events#CALENDAR_ID
```

The issue **get resolved** if i changed the :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

**But i want to develop my application for**

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

What should i do for that, please suggest me. How should i resolve the warning? and what effect the warning can do on my app.

Answer (score 0):

check programmatically the build.version and then put the code for the **api** level **14** inside the if condition.

so you don't have to do it in **manifest** xml,so you can run the code in minimum version devices.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

    put the code for api level 14

    }
```

Comment: If I put your suggestions in my code then is it set reminder for API level 8?

Comment: CalenderContract is only for api level 14 and above.so you cannot use it in lesser levels.